# How can I boot Ubuntu without using grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, grub-efi

Grub is very neat and all, but in my installation of Ubuntu it's only capable of booting into Ubuntu, and nor my Hackintosh or Windows partitions because it corrupts the MBR. Is there another boot manager apart from grub that can also boot Linux (and maybe grub itself)? By the way, I do not mean booting Windows or OSX from grub.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: I'm confused by your question (maybe others are too) Grub consists of a few parts; stage 1 is the MBR, so why would grub corrupt itself?  (the MBR is the first sector of a HDD/sdd).  Anyway yes there are other boot-loaders, eg. LiLo

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/best-linux-boot-loaders/

Comment: @guiverc yes it corrupts my mbr and lilo is nice and all, tried it, still couldn't boot other partitions